# My algorithm is a bit off and super inefficient

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm trying to implement algorithm called **Sum of Pairs** on **Codewars** website. I have written an algorithm but it does not pass all tests and it takes a lot of time to process. Please can you suggest me how to solve it correctly and efficiently. Thanks!

Instructions are following

```
sum_pairs([11, 3, 7, 5],         10)
#              ^--^      3 + 7 = 10
== [3, 7]

sum_pairs([4, 3, 2, 3, 4],         6)
#          ^-----^         4 + 2 = 6, indices: 0, 2 *
#             ^-----^      3 + 3 = 6, indices: 1, 3
#                ^-----^   2 + 4 = 6, indices: 2, 4
#  * entire pair is earlier, and therefore is the correct answer
== [4, 2]

sum_pairs([0, 0, -2, 3], 2)
#  there are no pairs of values that can be added to produce 2.
== None/nil/undefined (Based on the language)

sum_pairs([10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5],         10)
#              ^-----------^   5 + 5 = 10, indices: 1, 5
#                    ^--^      3 + 7 = 10, indices: 3, 4 *
#  * entire pair is earlier, and therefore is the correct answer
== [3, 7]
```

My code is:

```
var sum_pairs=function(ints, s){
    var total = 0;
    var list = [];
    for (var i=0; i < ints.length; i++) {
      for (var j=1; j < ints.length; j++) {
          total = ints[i]+ints[j];
          if (total === s) {
            list.push(ints[i], ints[j]); 
            return list;
        }  
        //console.log(total);
      }
    }
}

sum_pairs([1,2,3,4,1,0], 2);
```

And it does not pass this test:

```
✘ First Match From Left REDUX!: [10,5,2,3,7,5] should return [3, 7] for sum = 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use O(N^2) algorithms if you expect arrays of 10M elements. How about code below:

```
var sum_pairs=function(ints, s, und){
    var h = {}
    for(var i=ints.length - 1; i >= 0; --i){
      h[ints[i]] = i
    }
    for(var i=0; i < ints.length; ++i){
      var ci = ints[i]
      var e = h[s - ci]
      if(e < i){
        return [s - ci, ci]
      }
    }
    return und
}
```

Comment: It is the usage of a hash. For each element you only do constant number of operations, instead of a linear number like in other solutions. Try analyzing the algorithm, I will check tomorrow if you have any questions I will be happy to answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Btw what path can you recommend to master algorithms efficiency? Maybe some books and other resources.  I want primarily write in javascript so far as i want to learn properly one language to begin with.

Comment: I learned most of what I know about algorithms from Topcoder. https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/

Comment: I will look at it. Thanks!

Comment: so this solution takes more than my solution. 646 vs 606 ms.

Comment: @NinaScholz probably there are lots of duplicate numbers in the test cases. I am confident my solution will win if the numbers are mostly distinct, because "indexOf" hides another loop, so your solution is O(N^2)

Comment: you are right, but now it goes in 160 ms with a single loop and a hash table check tor the complement value.

Comment: What does double minus before variable i mean?

Comment: @NZMAI, it is a [prefix decrement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Decrement) operator, which decrements the variable by `1` and returns the actual value.

Comment: Can you decrement a variable by putting - after a variable?

Comment: @NZMAI, yes, like `i--;`

Answer (score 3):

Try this code, works in all cases.
Edit: I have made the loop parse only once, and uses a hash. This is a better solution than before. Runs at ~5000ms. Try going through this thread to know more about this logic: [Link](https://forum.freecodecamp.com/t/sum-of-pairs-algorithm-problem-stuck-for-a-week/44806/16)

```
var sum_pairs=function(arr, num){
var len=arr.length,i,j,hash = {},first_index,second_index;
for(i=0;i<len;i++){
  var looking_for = num - arr[i]
  if(looking_for in hash){
    first_index = hash[looking_for];
    second_index = i;
    return [arr[first_index], arr[second_index]];
  }
  hash[arr[i]] = i;      
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Your code is workable and it is worth to review for me and to learn more!

Comment: Yes. I have added a line `if( i == smallest_index) break;`, which reduces the load even further. Try this codepen: http://codepen.io/shahabaz/pen/EWPMQV?editors=1111 , uncomment the line and see the value of `count` decreasing significantly.

Comment: Anyway it does not help. It says: Process was terminated. It took longer than 12000ms to complete. You can try it yourself https://www.codewars.com/kata/sum-of-pairs/train/javascript

Comment: Actually it says all tests completed in 7ms. I think it was server load that took 12000ms. It's definitely not gonna take 12 seconds to run that code, unless its a really huge input array!

Comment: Yes it is a really huge array)))

Comment: Try clicking Run Examples button, it says 'You passed all tests!'. I don't know how this site works, where does it define the input array?

Comment: For sure but it does not accept if you click submit button. It simply means that creators of the algorithm assume that it is efficient enough to pass all tests. That is why it is necessary to write efficient algorithm. Anyway thank you for solution. To be honest my knowledge so far does not allow me to implement efficient algorithm.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137046/discussion-between-shah-abaz-khan-and-nzmai).

Answer (score 1):

Now with some speeding mechanisms, like

- single loop,
- hash table for visited values
- variable `a` for element `array[i]`

Long list needs **153 ms**.

```js
var sum_pairs = function (array, s) {
    var a, i,
        hash = Object.create(null);

    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        a = array[i];
        if (hash[s - a]) {
            return [s - a, a];
        }
        if (!hash[a]) {
            hash[a] = true;
        }
    }
};

console.log(sum_pairs([11, 3, 7, 5], 10));        // [3, 7]
console.log(sum_pairs([4, 3, 2, 3, 4], 6));       // [4, 2]
console.log(sum_pairs([0, 0, -2, 3], 2));         // undefined
console.log(sum_pairs([10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5], 10));  // [3, 7]
console.log(sum_pairs([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 0], 2));    // [1, 1]
console.log(sum_pairs([1, -2, 3, 0, -6, 1], -6)); // [0, -6]
console.log(sum_pairs([0, 2, 0], 0));             // [0, 0]
console.log(sum_pairs([5, 9, 13, -3], 10));       // [13, -3]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you for reply! Unfortunately some of the tests do not pass. For example:

✘ Negatives: [1,-2,3,0,-6,1] should return [0, -6] for sum = -6
✘ Zeroes: [0,2,0] should return [0, 0] for sum = 0
✘ Subtraction: [5,9,13,-3] should return [13, -3] for sum = 10

Comment: Yep it works! Is there a way to write it more efficiently? Because test system stall when there 10 thouthands numbers in an array!

Comment: Anyway it does not help. It says: Process was terminated. It took longer than 12000ms to complete. You can try it yourself 
https://www.codewars.com/kata/sum-of-pairs/train/javascript

Comment: you could copy both parts and have a look to the runtime

Comment: I do not why someone marked your answer as useless!?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var sum_pairs=function(ints, s){
    var total = 0;
    var list = [];
    //skip the last num
    for (var i=0; i < ints.length-1; i++) {
      //skip nums which is greater than s
      if(ints[i]>=s){
        continue;
      }
      //start from i+1 
      for (var j=i+1; j < ints.length; j++) {
          total = ints[i]+ints[j];
          if (total === s) {
            list.push(ints[i], ints[j]); 
            return list;
        }  
        //console.log(total);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Kajal thanks, but unfortunately your code does not pass tests. For example:
✘ First Match From Left REDUX!: [10,5,2,3,7,5] should return [3, 7] for sum = 10