# javascript optimization for pair finding algorithm

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization

I am working on a javascript function which takes an array of integers and a target as arguments. The task is to find the first pair of integers in the array whose sum is equal to the target.  I have tried this several different ways, but I keep getting a timeout error for larger input arrays. Can someone please give me some pointers on how to better optimize this code? Thanks!

```
var sum_pairs = function(ints, s){
  var r = [];
  var a = true;
  var l = ints.length;
  for(var j = 0; j < l; j++){
    if(a){
      for(var i = 0; i < j; i++){
        if(ints[j] + ints[i] == s){
          r[0] = ints[i];
          r[1] = ints[j];
          a = false;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    else{
      console.log('breaking');
      break;
    }
  }
return r[0] == null ? null : r;
}
```

Comment: it looks like sum of pairs from codewars. maybe you have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42551366/my-algorithm-is-a-bit-off-and-super-inefficient/42551929#42551929

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/138213/codewars-sum-of-pairs/138216

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't really for "how do I optimize code" kinds of questions. Those are typically better suited to [codereview.se]. But, as @PriyeshKumar has helpfully pointed out, it appears to have already been asked there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My algorithm is a bit off and super inefficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42551366/my-algorithm-is-a-bit-off-and-super-inefficient)

Comment: would sorting the array first make it better?

Comment: no, sorting is in the best average case O(nlogn), then you need to iterate again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use some speeding mechanisms, like

- single loop,
- hash table for visited values
- variable `a` for element `array[i]`
- very short variable names (just kidding)

[Long list](https://www.codewars.com/kata/sum-of-pairs/train/javascript) needs **153 ms**.

```js
var sum_pairs = function (array, s) {
    var a, i,
        hash = Object.create(null);

    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        a = array[i];
        if (hash[s - a]) {
            return [s - a, a];
        }
        if (!hash[a]) {
            hash[a] = true;
        }
    }
};

console.log(sum_pairs([11, 3, 7, 5], 10));        // [3, 7]
console.log(sum_pairs([4, 3, 2, 3, 4], 6));       // [4, 2]
console.log(sum_pairs([0, 0, -2, 3], 2));         // undefined
console.log(sum_pairs([10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5], 10));  // [3, 7]
console.log(sum_pairs([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 0], 2));    // [1, 1]
console.log(sum_pairs([1, -2, 3, 0, -6, 1], -6)); // [0, -6]
console.log(sum_pairs([0, 2, 0], 0));             // [0, 0]
console.log(sum_pairs([5, 9, 13, -3], 10));       // [13, -3]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

For each number that we encounter while iterating the array, we add that number's expected partner `target - number` into a `Set`. As soon as we encounter a number that is already in our set, we know that its partner has already been encountered and return this pair as the solution:

```js
// Return the first two values of 'numbers' summing up to 'target':
function sum_pairs(numbers, target) {
  let paired = new Set();
  for (let number of numbers) {
    if (paired.has(number)) return [target - number, number];
    paired.add(target - number);
  }
}

// Examples:
console.log(...sum_pairs([9, 3, 7, 5, 1], 10)); // [3, 7]
console.log(...sum_pairs([4, 3, 2, 3, 4],  6)); // [4, 2]
console.log(...sum_pairs([9, 3, 6, 4, 1], 10)); // [6, 4]
```

This implementation has a linear runtime complexity and is therefore faster for long input arrays, but it comes with an additional memory cost.

If you are going for raw speed, replace the for-of loop with a traditional for-loop and the `let` variable binding with a `var` declaration.

Comment: your approach is faster than Nina's on long input arrays how?

Comment: @Arrow Faster than OP's implementation. Same runtime complexity as NIna's solution.